# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Below is my code to add data to a database. I use SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio community. I have created a database `WebPageMovies` in the server. I can see the database in the server explorer window, but not in the solution explorer window. But while running it, it returns an error

> Connection string "WebPagesMovies" was not found

Code:

```
@{    
var title = "";
var genre = "";
var year = "";

if (IsPost)
{
    title = Request.Form["title"];
    genre = Request.Form["genre"];
    year = Request.Form["year"];

    var db = Database.Open("WebPagesMovies");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Movies (Title, Genre, Year) Values(@0, @1, @2)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, title, genre, year);
    Response.Redirect("~/Movies");
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is my web.config file. Where shall I add it?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Where shall I add it? Plz help

Answer (score 7):

You can add it in multiple ways i.e. either in the `<appSettings></appSettings>` tag or even in a `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>` tag

```
<appSettings>
<add key="WebPagesMovies" value="your database credentials"/>
<appSettings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="WebPagesMovies" connectionString="your database credentials"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

After doing this read the connection string in your .cs file in which you are accessing your database.

```
private  readonly SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebPagesMovies"]);
```

or

```
 private  readonly SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebPagesMovies"]);
```

respectively depending on where you have added the connectionstring(`<Appsettings>` or `<conncetionstrings>`).

Answer (score 3):

There must be a connectionString called "WebPagesMovies" in your project web.config file. If not, create one.

You can add it just below `<system.web>` as shown below.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="WebPagesMovies"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Change your databasename, server name accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Check your web.config for the connection string named WebPagesMovies is exists.